# Where is the error in Chudnovsky algorithm (python)?

Tags: python-3.x, pi

I'm new to python (and coding too) so I'm following a tutorial book. I'm try to calculate pi to a set number of decimal places using the Chudnovsky algorithm from code outlined in the book; however, when I execute the code I get an error saying:

```
> File "C:/Users/user/Documents/Python/Scripts/Tutorials/Calculating
> pi.py", line 15, in calc
> t = (Decimal(-1)**k)*(math.factorial(Decimal(6)*k))*(13591409 + 545140134*k) TypeError: 'decimal.Decimal' object cannot be interpreted
> as an integer
```

Here is the original code:

```
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext
import math
    
    numberofdigits = int(input("please enter the number of decimal places to calculate Pi to: "))
    getcontext().prec = numberofdigits
    
    def calc(n):
        t = Decimal(0)
        pi = Decimal(0)
        deno = Decimal(0)
        k = 0
        for k in range(n):
            t = (Decimal(-1)**k)*(math.factorial(Decimal(6)*k))*(13591409+545140134*k)
            deno = math.factorial(3*k)*(math.factorial(k)**Decimal(3))*(640320**(3*k))
            pi += Decimal(t)/Decimal(deno)
        pi = pi * Decimal(12)/Decimal(640320**Decimal(1.5))
        pi = 1/pi
        return str(pi)
    
    
    print (calc(1))
```

Where am I going wrong here? I have triple checked for spelling errors etc. but have not found anything but don't really understand what the decimal.decimal type error means.

EDIT:
I've been playing around with it and found that if I separate the terms of the numerator I get:

```
 def calc(n): 
    t = Decimal(0) 
    pi = Decimal(0) 
    deno = Decimal(0) 
    k = 0 for k in range(n): 
    u=(Decimal(-1)**k) 
    x=(Decimal(6)*k) 
    v=math.factorial(x) 
    w=(13591409+545140134*k) 
    t = u*v*w 
    deno = math.factorial(3*k)*(math.factorial(k)**Decimal(3))*(640320**(3*k))
```

This gives me the following error:

line 17, in calc v=math.factorial(x) TypeError: 'decimal.Decimal' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Cheers

Comment: What input are you using? Your code works for me without any errors.

Comment: I only put in 10 or 20 as the input, nothing ridiculous. Is that a common 'type error' to do with the decimal.decimal?

Comment: Could it be because of some disgreement between producing a float but wanting to produce an integer?

Comment: This is odd. It looks like an issue with iPython notebooks, there is a discussion about it on Github: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/10367

Comment: I haven't heard of iPython notebooks before, I am using the python 3.8.3 shell and creating new files in that, saving them and then executing them. Are they the same thing?

Comment: Ok, I think I figured it out, let me know if my answer helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the `math.factorial()` function accepts only integers or floats with integral values, but does not support `Decimal` objects:

```
print(math.factorial(6))
# 720
print(math.factorial(6.0))
# 720
print(math.factorial(Decimal(6)))
# TypeError: 'decimal.Decimal' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Changing the value passed to `math.factorial()` on line 15 should fix the error:

```
t = (Decimal(-1)**k) * (math.factorial(6 * k)) * (13591409+545140134 * k)
```

Interestingly, your original code works fine using Python 3.6.9, but fails in Python 3.8.2, because this behavior was introduced in Python 3.8 (yes, this is the intended behavior).

The logic behind this behavior can be fully understood by reading this discussion about dropping support for Decimal objects in `math.factorial()`:

[Issue 33083: math.factorial accepts non-integral Decimal instances](https://bugs.python.org/issue33083)

Comment: Yes, this sorted the problem. Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: Glad I could help you out, this was actually an interesting question, nice catch!

Comment: I'm glad that it was something obscure to do with python and not me being inept, now I can finish the rest of that particular tutorial