# Python stat_env: I keep getting a TypeError: 'decimal.Decimal' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python

I cant figure out why I get:

```
TypeError: 'decimal.Decimal' object cannot be interpreted as an integer.
```

To do this I am using a statistics python environment `stat_env`. I suspect it's because the list `S` but don't know how to fix it.

It doesn't like this line:

```
return Decimal(Decimal(l)**Decimal(k))*Decimal(math.exp(Decimal(-l)))/Decimal(math.factorial(Decimal(k)))
```

Here's the full code:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from decimal import Decimal

def poisson(l,k):
    return Decimal(Decimal(l)**Decimal(k))*Decimal(math.exp(Decimal(-l)))/Decimal(math.factorial(Decimal(k)))

n=1000
p=0.003
l=n*p
S=[]

for i in range(0,n):
    S.append(poisson(l,i))

len_x=18
b=range(0,len_x+1)
plt.close('all')
plt.stem(b,S[0:len_x+1])
title='Bernoulli Trials: PMF - Poisson Approximation'
xlabel='Number of successes in n='+str(n)+' trials'
ylabel='Probability'
plt.title(title)
plt.xlabel(xlabel)
plt.ylabel(ylabel)
plt.xticks(b)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is the error in Chudnovsky algorithm (python)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63018438/where-is-the-error-in-chudnovsky-algorithm-python)

Comment: That line is all one formula

Comment: I found your issue and deleted my comment; see that linked answer for the explanation. The way I found it was by breaking it up into multiple lines. I can post an answer explaining this.

Comment: I looked at your link but I still don't now how to break that up into multiple lines

Comment: I posted an answer with an example of what I meant. In Python, or any language, you're free to define parts of an expression beforehand, and evaluate the various parts bit by bit rather than doing it all in one line. Hopefully you get it after seeing my example. That link wasn't how to break things up into multiple lines, but instead it's just a duplicate of your issue, where they're trying to do a factorial on a Decimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know what line your error was on but not which actual function call was giving an error:

```
return Decimal(Decimal(l)**Decimal(k))*Decimal(math.exp(Decimal(-l)))/Decimal(math.factorial(Decimal(k)))
```

In order to determine which part failed, we can break up the expression into all separate lines, while keeping everything equivalent. Obviously the line is all one formula, but we can pre-define/pre-calculate all the various parts of the line before returning the result:

```
a = Decimal(l)
b = Decimal(k)
c = Decimal(a**b)
d = Decimal(-l)
e = math.exp(d)
f = Decimal(e)
g = math.factorial(b)
h = Decimal(g)
return c*f/h
```

When running the code now, Python tells us the exact line the error is happening on:

```
g = math.factorial(b)
```

Thus, we can determine that `math.factorial()` cannot accept a Decimal, and therefore requires an integer. Luckily, `b` corresponds to `Decimal(k)`, and `k` is an integer, so replacing that expression with `math.factorial(k)` fixes the issue.